# How do I mock a method defined in a Moo Role?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, moose, moo

Given the following Role:

```
package MyRole;
use Moo::Role;

sub foo { 
    return 'blah';
}
```

And the following consuming class:

```
package MyClass;
use Moo;
with 'MyRole';

around foo = sub { 
    my ($orig, $self) = @_;
    return 'bak' if $self->$orig eq 'baz';
    return $self->$orig;
}
```

I would like to test behaviour defined in the `around` modifier. How do I do this? It seems that Test::MockModule won't work:

```
use MyClass;
use Test::Most;
use Test::MockModule;

my $mock = Test::MockModule->new('MyRole');
$mock->mock('foo' => sub { return 'baz' });

my $obj = MyClass->new;
# Does not work
is $obj->foo, 'bak', 'Foo is what it oughtta be';
```

**EDIT**: What I'm looking to test is the *interaction* of MyClass with MyRole as defined in the `around` modifier. I want to test that the code in the `around` modifier does what I think it should. Here's another example that's closer to my actual code:

```
package MyRole2
use Moo::Role;

sub call {
    my $self = shift;
    # Connect to server, retrieve a document
    my $document = $self->get_document;
    return $document;
}

package MyClass2;
use Moo;
with 'MyRole2';

around call = sub { 
    my ($orig, $self) = @_;
    my $document = $self->$orig;
    if (has_error($document)) {
        die 'Error';
    }
    return parse($document);
};
```

So what I want to do here is to mock `MyRole2::call` to return a static document, defined in my test fixtures, that contains errors and test that the exception is thrown properly. I know how to test it using `Test::More::throws_ok` or similar. What I don't know how to do is to mock *MyRole2::call* and **not** `MyClass2::call`.

Comment: [Mock::Sub](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mock::Sub) can mock individual subs: `my $m=Mock::Sub->new; my $foo=$m->mock('MyRole::foo'); MyRole::foo(); print "$foo->called_count; #etc`. I've never tested it with `Moo` though, which is why this isn't an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From mst on #moose:

```
use 5.016;
use Test::Most tests => 1;

require MyRole;

our $orig = MyRole->can('foo');
no warnings 'redefine';
*MyRole::foo = sub { goto &$orig };

{
    local $orig = sub {'baz'};
    require MyClass;
    my $obj = MyClass->new;
    is $obj->foo, 'bak', 'Foo is what it oughtta be'; 
}
```

The trick is to override MyRole::foo *before* anything that uses it gets loaded. Which means using `require MyClass` instead of `use MyClass`, because `use MyClass` translates to `BEGIN { require MyClass }` which defeats the whole thing of overriding the method *before* anything using it gets loaded.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with [`Test::MockModule`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::MockModule)

These were the minor changes required:

1. `around foo {` should be written `around foo => sub {` since `around` takes a subroutine reference.
2. `$self->$orig` needed to be written as `$self->($orig)`
3. The documentation lists it as `my ($orig, $self) = @_;` so I changed it to  `$orig->($self);`

Here is a working version:

**MyRole.pm**

```
package MyRole;
use Moo::Role;

sub foo { 
    return 'foo blah';
}

sub bar { 
    return 'bar blah';
}

1;
```

**MyClass.pm**

```
package MyClass;

use Moo;
with 'MyRole';

around foo => sub { 
    my ($orig, $self) = (@_);
    my ($result) = $orig->($self);
    return 'bak' if $result eq 'baz'; # Will never return 'bak' as coded.
    return $result;
};
```

**test.t**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use MyClass;
use Test::Most;
use Test::MockModule;

my $obj = MyClass->new;
# foo has an around block, bar does not
is($obj->bar, 'bar blah', 'bar() returns [ bar blah ]');
is($obj->foo, 'foo blah', 'foo() returns [ foo blah ]');

my $mock = Test::MockModule->new('MyClass');
$mock->mock('foo' => sub { return 'mocked foo blah' } );

my $mocked = MyClass->new;
is($mocked->bar, 'bar blah', 'bar() still returns [ bar blah ]');
is($mocked->foo, 'mocked foo blah', 'foo() now returns mocked answer [ mocked foo blah ]');
```

**Run it**

```
prove -v test.t
test.t .. 
ok 1 - bar() returns [ bar blah ]
ok 2 - foo() returns [ foo blah ]
ok 3 - bar() still returns [ bar blah ]
ok 4 - foo() now returns mocked answer [ mocked foo blah ]
1..4
ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=4,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.06 usr  0.01 sys +  0.19 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.26 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

Please have a look:

[Class::Method::Modifiers::around()](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Class-Method-Modifiers-2.12/lib/Class/Method/Modifiers.pm#around_method(s)_=%3E_sub_%7B_..._%7D;)

Comment: `$self->$orig` is the same as `$orig->($self)`.

Comment: I thought so too, but it worked one way, but fails the other.  Go figure.

Comment: If I remove the parens, I get `Can't call method "MyClass=HASH(0x9cde33c)" on unblessed reference at MyClass.pm line 9.
`

Comment: That's what happens when you swap the variables and do `$orig->$self`.

Comment: In this example, it may be better to just use `my ($orig) = shift; ... ; $orig->( @_ );` depending on what the OP actually wants to do in his `around`

Comment: My apologies - I tossed that off quickly without looking at syntax, and have corrected the syntax in the OP.


It's clear that I have failed to make clear what I'm looking to accomplish. I want to test the behavior in the `around` modifier.  To use my example above, I want MyRole::foo to return 'bak' *in the test*.

I think I chose a poor example. I'll edit the OP.